# ActiveRecord find categories which contain at least one item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Support I have two models for items and categories, in a many-to-many relation

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories 

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
```

Now I want to filter out categories which contain at least one items, what will be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**please notice, what the other guys answererd is NOT performant!**

*the most performant solution:*

better to work with a **counter_cache** and save the items_count in the model!

```
scope :with_items, where("items_count > 0")


has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :after_add=>:update_count, :after_remove=>:update_count

def update_count(category)
  category.items_count = category.items.count
  category.save
end
```

for normal "belongs_to" relation you just write

```
belongs_to :parent, :counter_cache=>true
```

and in the parent_model you have an field items_count (items is the pluralized has_many class name)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

in a has_and_belongs_to_many relation you have to write it as your own as above

Comment: It may be less performant, but it relies on the RDBMS to maintain consistency (something they're specifically designed for). Depending on how Rails does the after_add callback (whether or not it's in a transaction, for instance), you could end up with inconsistent counts.

Comment: you can write tests for this cases, wrap transactions around it. thats not the problem. but take the fact: you have 2500 categories, they all have 10-500 articles inside. do you know how big the query would be? :)

Comment: Do YOU know how big the query would be? Inner joining is very fast, your saving even for thousands of records would be minimal. And you're making an assumption about the amount of times the categories and items are inserted/added vs the number of times they're selected. So it *might not* be more performant

Comment: working with countercache and not using joins should be the most performant action? or im wrong?

Comment: maybe we could do a testcase with maybe 15.000 categories in 500 different top_categories. and - (but at least it doesnt matters, because we are working with fragment_cache on the frontend :) )

Comment: Good thinking, I have something similar on a smaller scale to demonstrate: 8,000 'items' with a many-to-many against 20 'categories' (smaller scale that we might have wanted but this is a real project). Selecting the distinct categories:

*select distinct name from categories #20 records in 0.5ms*

Selecting the distinct categories that have associated items:

*select distinct c.name from categories c
inner join items_to_categories ic on ic.category_id = c.id # 18 records in 0.5ms*

So the latter query has to negotiate more than 10,000 joining records to get that result.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to echo @Delba's answer and expand on it because it's correct - what @huan son is suggesting with the count column is completely unnecessary, if you have your indexes set up correctly.

I would add that you probably want to use .uniq, as it's a many-to-many you only want DISTINCT categories to come back:

```
Category.joins(:items).uniq
```

Using the joins query will let you more easily work conditions into your count of items too, giving much more flexibility. For example you might not want to count items where enabled = false:

```
Category.joins(:items).where(:items => { :enabled => true  }).uniq
```

This would generate the following SQL, using inner joins which are EXTREMELY fast:

```
SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` INNER JOIN `categories_items` ON `categories_items`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` INNER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`id` = `categories_items`.`item_id` WHERE `items`.`enabled` = 1
```

Good luck,
Stu

Answer (score 1):

```
Category.joins(:items)
```

More details here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :has_item, where("#{table_name}.id IN (SELECT categories_items.category_id FROM categories_items")
```

This will return all categories which have an entry in the join table because, ostensibly, a category shouldn't have an entry there if it does not have an item.  You could add a `AND categories_items.item_id IS NOT NULL` to the subselect condition just to be sure.

In case you're not aware, `table_name` is a method which returns the table name of ActiveRecord class calling it.  In this case it would be `"categories"`.