# Is it possible to use a condition with count on a has_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, conditional-statements

I have a project list and want to display only projects that have tasks. Is it possible to use a condition with count on a has_many relation?

```
# get my project list
Project.includes(:tasks).where(...)

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
```

Currently i am doing this through a loop but i dont think that this is the right way.

Comment: I have asked similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227557/activerecord-find-categories-which-contain-at-least-one-item). Hope it can help you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already eager loading the tasks for a project you can use the following statement to get the projects with tasks.

```
# get my project list
Project.includes(:tasks).where("tasks.id IS NOT NULL")
```

This works because `includes` uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

On the other hand if you don't want to eager load the tasks, you can use `joins` as it uses INNER JOIN.

```
Project.joins(:tasks).where(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `includes` directive often indicates to simply eager-load those associations, not `JOIN` them in database-wise, so you can't really do conditions here without some additional work.

One way that scales well is to use the `counter_cache` feature of the association so you always have a numerical count of the number of tasks. You can even add an index on these to further improve the performance of your query.

The alternative is to try and work backwards from the `tasks` table, perhaps like:

```
Project.where('id IN (SELECT DISTINCT project_id FROM tasks)')
```

Presumably you have an index on `project_id` in your `tasks` table to make that a fairly inexpensive operation.

Comment: you don't need `counter_cache` for this. Since the `includes` directive is being used the underlying SQL generated uses LEFT OUTER JOIN. It is a matter of doing a not null check. The scenario is much simpler if user uses `joins`. I have discussed this in my answer below.

Comment: I'm of the mind that it's better to not load things you don't need. If a project has a kabillion tasks, loading them all without restriction could crush the app.

Comment: I understand, that is the general pre-caution one has to take while opting for eager loading.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is as simple as the title suggests, not sure why this wouldn't do the trick:

```
Project.joins(:tasks)
```

Unless specified otherwise, the join will be an inner join, and thus exclude any results whose projects do not have tasks, so perhaps that's all you need ... if you want to display *all* projects with tasks.

If you have some condition (for example, projects whose status is active) you can also specify a condition like

```
Project.joins(:tasks).where("status = 'active')
```

Or have I missed something?